# Should you be able to access a 169.254 Link Local address from a computer with a DHCP allocated address?

Tags: linux, networking

We have our own embedded PC running Linux. The current image allows us to set a link-local address on the embedded PC, which can be used to make a TCP connection from any computer on the same local network segment (i.e. as long as we're not going through a router) even if that computer is on a different subnet.

> e.g.  Embedded PC: 169.254.80.72 Subnet 255.255.0.0
>
> Computer: 192.168.0.5 Subnet 255.255.255.0

With this configuration, we can ping and ssh to the embedded PC using the link-local address from the computer. e.g. ping 169.254.80.72

Our problem is that we've just upgraded the kernel of the embedded PC, and this no longer works; the computer must also be on a link-local address in order to see the embedded PC.

Arp now shows the IP address to be always incomplete. The older images report a hardware address, as you would expect.

```
arp -a

? (169.254.126.190) at (incomplete) on en0 [ethernet]
```

It is like the embedded PC can no longer respond to IP addresses that are not directly on its link-local subnet.

I thought that any computer should be able to access a link-local address from anywhere on the same local network subnet regardless of the primary IP address that it has been allocated. Is this correct? Is this true for Mac, Linux and Windows?

Have we lost a setting? Or should this never have worked?

Is there a Linux setting that would re-enable this functionality on the new image?

Is there any benefit in moving to IPv6?

Comment: Which Linux distribution and what are the old and new version numbers?

Comment: It should never have worked. The subnet mask would need to be 0.0.0.0 and would basically exclude no network addresses to talk to that machine. [it is not a valid subnet mask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709485/how-do-i-set-netmask-to-0-0-0-0-or-0)

Comment: 192.168.0.5 with 255.255.255.0 as the subnet mask should only be able to connect to machines that start with 192.168.0, so from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255. With 169.254.80.72 and subnet 255.255.0.0 it should allow everything from 169.254.0.0 to 196.254.255.255